# Id selector not working for input type submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read a table when I click on total button,the button is created on ajax call with table I tried with both id attribute and input type submit selectors but I am not able to read the button,but when I tried to call javascript function on button click the javascript function is called,can anyone explain this and how should I read using jquery selectors

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',    
        url:'/pos/addproduct',
        dataType: "json",
        data:JSON.stringify(order),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success:
            function(data){
             i++;
             console.log(i);
            $.each(data,function(index,value){
                var temp = "qty" + data[index].barcodeid.trim();
                var qtyitm=$("#"+temp);

                if(qtyitm.length != 0){
                    qtyitm.html(data[index].qty);
                    //("#price"+(data[index].barcodeid.trim())).html(data[index].price);
                    temp = "price" + data[index].barcodeid.trim();
                    qtyitm = $("#"+temp);
                    qtyitm.html(data[index].price);
                }
                else{
                    var row=$("<tr><td>"+data[index].oid+"</td>"+"<td>"+data[index].pname.trim()+
                            "</td>"+
                            "<td id=\"qty"+data[index].barcodeid.trim()+"\">"+data[index].qty+"</td>"+
                            "<td id=\"price"+data[index].barcodeid.trim()+"\">"+data[index].price+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"
                            +data[index].barcodeid.trim()+"</td></tr>"

                    );
                    $("#firstrow").after(row).removeClass("hidden");
                    }

            })
            if(i==1){
            var row1=$("<tr><td>"+'<input type="submit" id="calculateTotal" value="Total">'+"</td></tr>");
            $("#order tbody").append(row1);
            }
        }

})
});
$('input[id="calculateTotal"]').click(function(event){
    alert("hello");
})
```

[image: id selector not working]

Comment: javascript method of parsing is the reason...when you link you code say js when the page is loaded browser parse it in that case your dynamically added button does not exits and no event listener is bound to it... Solution is use $(document).ready() and use $('document').on('click','id/class selector',function(){ //do your stuff here });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the submit button `#calculateTotal` was added dynamically via js code in :

```
$("<tr><td>"+'<input type="submit" id="calculateTotal" value="Total">'+"</td></tr>");
```

You should use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to attach `click` event to it, like :

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[id="calculateTotal"]', function(event){
    alert("hello");
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Browser parses your javascript code when your page is loaded and attaches event listeners to DOM elements in your initial loading (in that case your button does not exits as you simply attach it to existing DOM tree [hence no event bound] )

Solution is use `$('document').on('event','selector','callback')` so with you code :

```
var row1=$("<tr><td>"+'<input type="submit" id="calculateTotal" value="Total">'+"</td></tr>");
            $("#order tbody").append(row1);
```

and in Js:

`$('document').on('click','#calculateTotal',function(){
 //do your stuff here 
});`

Hope it helps...:D